# Kafka compression type version -0.10.0.1

Tags: apache-kafka, snappy

I have been testing the kafka compression type using performance testing tool.
Basically I use the built-in tool to send 1000000 messages to kafka cluster with different compression mode. What i can see the compression is working with gzip, and lz4, but data seems not getting compression for snappy type.

Furthermore, I also checked network traffic for snappy, it is compressed at client side, but seems having problem at brokers.

storage before sending:

```
5.0K    ./test_none-0
1.0K    ./test_gzip-0
3.0K    ./test_snappy-0
1.0K    ./test_lz4-0
```

run following command to publish 1M messages to server

```
/home/sysgenu/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --num-records 1000000 --throughput 100000 --record-size 1000 --topic test_none --producer-props bootstrap.servers=ldnpsr000001131:9092,gbrcsr000000096:9092
/home/sysgenu/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --num-records 1000000 --throughput 100000 --record-size 1000 --topic test_snappy --producer-props bootstrap.servers=ldnpsr000001131:9092,gbrcsr000000096:9092 compression.type=snappy
/home/sysgenu/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --num-records 1000000 --throughput 100000 --record-size 1000 --topic test_gzip --producer-props bootstrap.servers=ldnpsr000001131:9092,gbrcsr000000096:9092 compression.type=gzip
/home/sysgenu/kafka/kafka_2.10-0.10.0.1/bin/kafka-producer-perf-test.sh --num-records 1000000 --throughput 100000 --record-size 1000 --topic test_lz4 --producer-props bootstrap.servers=ldnpsr000001131:9092,gbrcsr000000096:9092 compression.type=lz4
```

Check storage after publishing

```
494M    ./test_none-0
96M     ./test_gzip-0
500M    ./test_snappy-0
25M     ./test_lz4-0
```

I dont why nothing happy for snappy?

Appreciate for any help?

Comment: It might be caused by the fact that the current default block size (1K) used in Snappy is too small as described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-3704.

Comment: Thanks @amethystic   can you advise how to change default buffer size when producing record? which parameter needs to be set?

Comment: I mean to say is there any other config from producer to influnce this factor?

Comment: Seems that there is no config that you could change this behavior.

Comment: I have changed to the message size to 100, and the compression happened. I think becuase the message size is greater than the buffer size for the snappy, so the compression is ignored.